# (Terraform) Unsuitable value for left operand: a number is required

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

On **GCP**, I'm trying to run **the Cloud Run service "renderer"** with the **Terraform** code below and  in this code, I concatenate **"gcr.io/"**, the variable **var.project_id** and **"/renderer:latest"** using **plus(+)**:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "renderer" {
  name     = "renderer"
  location = "asia-northeast1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/" + var.project_id + "/renderer:latest" // Here
      }
      service_account_name = google_service_account.renderer_identity.email
    }
  }

  traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }
}
```

Then, when I applied this code above, I got this error below:

```
Error: Invalid operand
 
  on 2nd.tf line 38, in resource "google_cloud_run_service" "renderer":
  38:         image = "gcr.io/" + var.project_id + "/renderer:latest"
 
Unsuitable value for left operand: a number is required.


Error: Invalid operand
 
  on 2nd.tf line 38, in resource "google_cloud_run_service" "renderer":
  38:         image = "gcr.io/" + var.project_id + "/renderer:latest"
 
Unsuitable value for right operand: a number is required.
```

Is it impossible to use **plus(+)** for **concatenation**? and if it's impossible, how do I do **concatenation** in **Terraform**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's impossible to use **plus(+)** for **concatenation** in **Terraform**. So, you need to use **"Interpolation Syntax" ${var.project_id}** for **concatenation** as shown below instead of **plus(+)**:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "renderer" {
  name     = "renderer"
  location = "asia-northeast1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/${var.project_id}/renderer:latest" // Here
      }
      service_account_name = google_service_account.renderer_identity.email
    }
  }

  traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }
}
```

In addition, you cannot use **plus(+)** for **concatenation** but you can use **plus(+)** for **calculation**. For example, your **Terraform** code has **"percent"** in **"traffic"** block:

```
traffic {
  percent         = 100
  latest_revision = true
}
```

Then, you can add **30** to **100** with **plus(+)**:

```
traffic {
  percent         = 100 + 30 // 130
  latest_revision = true
}
```

And, even **the numeric strings "100"** and **"30"** can be calculated as **Number types**:

```
traffic {
  percent         = "100" + "30" // 130 (Number type)
  latest_revision = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue when trying to create an **iam group** using **Terraform**.

The issue was caused by an indentation:

```
variable "iam_path" {
  type        = string
  description = "(Optional, default " / ") Path in which to create the group."
}
```

I was using double quotes `" / "` within the description double quotes.

All I had to do was remove the double quotes for `" / "` to be single quotes `' / '` or remove the quotes altogether. So we will have:

```
variable "iam_path" {
  type        = string
  description = "(Optional, default ' / ') Path in which to create the group."
}
```

OR

```
variable "iam_path" {
  type        = string
  description = "(Optional, default  / ) Path in which to create the group."
}
```